# The Regex `## Example[^]+### Response` cannot be matched

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large number of markdown files. In those files, I want to replace certain `### Response` to `### ResponseNew`

````
### Response
I don't want to replace this Response above to ResponseNew since it is not following Example

## Example
### Request
123{}```

### Response
I want to replace this Response above to ResponseNew since it is following Example
````

So I try to use

```
## Example[^]+### Response
```

to replace to

```
$&New
```

This works when I test in the [RegExr website](http://regexr.com/).

However, using Sublime to find and replace, it shows the error:

> Unmatched [ or [^ in character class declaration.  The error occurred
>   while parsing the regular expression fragment: '# Response>>>HERE>>>'.
>   in regular expression ## Example[^]+### Response

I also tried to use Perl in terminal following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/115348/mac-os-x-search-and-replace-tool-with-regular-expression-support),

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e "s/## Example[^]+### Response/$&New/g" {} \;
```

it shows:

> Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/## Example[ <-- HERE
>   ^]+### Response/ at -e line 1.

How can I write the Regex correctly so I can match? Thanks

Comment: The `[^]` idiom doesn't exist in Perl.

Comment: Regexr does not support Perl regex syntax. It is only useful to test JavaScript regex.

Comment: Is there any other Regex that I can use instead of [^]? Thanks

Comment: `(?s:.)`, `/./s`. Use `s` modifier with a dot. `[^]` in ECMAScript standard means *not nothing* = *any char*.

Comment: OTOH, Perl treats `[^]` as `[^\]...`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, I didn't realize Regex is different for different language

Comment: Post your Perl code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry how can I forget it! I am on phone, I will post in 10 min

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just added

Comment: I didn't see details of these comments before, please take note:  The original version of the question was rather unclear, with that `RegExR` and references to `Sublime`, and no Perl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file isn't too large

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/## Example.*?### Response\K/New/sg' markdown.txt
```

what prints the correct output with the provided input.

The [`/s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#*s*) modifier makes `.` match a newline as well, and `\K` makes it drop the previous matches so you don't have to "replace" them. So it tacks `New` right onto `Response` once it matches. The `-0777` switch makes it slurp the whole file into `$_`, needed in order to work across multiple lines.

If `### Response` may come in a middle of a line and you don't want to touch it there

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/## Example.*?^### Response\K/New/smg' markdown.txt
```

where [`/m`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#*m*) modifier makes `^` match beginning of each line, not only of the whole string.

---

If the file *is* too large to slurp into a variable, set a flag when `## Example` is found and then once `### Response` is found (with flag true) replace it and unset the flag.

This is feasable in a oneliner, if you must, but I'd recommend a short script.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Between the line by line and the slurp mode, you can also define your own record delimiter and choose `## Example`. Then all you have to do is to replace the first occurrence of `### Response` for each record:

```
perl -pe'BEGIN{$/="## Example"} s/### Response\K/New/ if $a++' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the info too!